# Edge-detecting on a continuous set of pixels?

Tags: java, scala, image-processing

I am writing a library for animation where inputs do not have any scale. Dimensions and scale are determined by the supplied rendering backend.

```
trait RenderingBackend {

  def render(w: Int, h: Int, f: File, d: Drawable, framerate: Int, totalTime: Long, unit: TimeUnit): Unit

}
```

I want to implement an edge-detection transformation

```
trait Transformation {

  def transform(t: Transformable): Transformable

}
```

that can be applied to a transformable

```
trait Transformable extends Drawable {

  def transform(t: Transformation): Transformable = t.transform(this)

}
```

given a color and a stroke radius. Where `Drawable` interface is

```
trait Drawable {

  /**
    * If the drawable does not contain (x, y) as a point, then this should return None.
    * If the drawable perfectly defines (x, y) as a point, then this should return the Some(color).
    * If the drawable does not perfectly define (x, y) as a point but does define points around it, a weighted average should be chosen.
    * @param x the x relative to the whole image to be retrieved
    * @param y the y relative to the whole image to be retrieved
    * @return an optional color
    */
  def color(x: Double, y: Double): (Double) => Option[Color]

  /**
    * Generates an image for a time.
    * Square resolutions work best.
    * @param w width of output
    * @param h height of output
    * @return function to generate an image based on time [0.0, 1.0)
    */
  def image(w: Int, h: Int): (Double) => BufferedImage = // some implementation using the color method

}
```

[Full code for `Drawable` can be found here.](https://hastebin.com/lihukuguzu.php)

A class implementing the `Transformable` trait gives a `(Double) => Option[Color]` back with `Some(_)` representing a defined color (part of the Transformable) and `None` representing the point *not* being part of the shape. However, the difference from Drawable is that this may be transformed.

What is meant by "continuous" is that there is no defining scale or resolution. For example, the color function of an ellipse is

```
(t) => {
  val (ph, pk) = pos(t)
  val rx = w(t) / 2
  val ry = h(t) / 2
  val c = (((x - ph) * (x - ph)) / (rx * rx)) + (((y - pk) * (y - pk)) / (ry * ry))
  if(c <= 1) {
    Some(color(t))
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```

It takes no scale, resolution, or units, just a point.

Since everything is continuous before rendering, how do I detect the edge of something via a `Transformation`?

Comment: How is this question related to Java?

Comment: @Turing85 Scala runs on the JVM, so a Java solution would be good as well. I can easily translate Java to Scala, and more people have experience with Java in this type of programming.

Comment: You should include this information in your question since it is not obvious that you would accept a java-solution as well.

Comment: I don't think your problem has any solution as defined now. Images are stored either in vector or raster formats: in a vector format you have shapes defined so they can be analyzed and drawn using some scale; in raster you have fixed scale, width, height, etc. You are trying to make some hybrid but don't store enough information: your image is scaleless but does not contain metadata about the shapes it is built from. This just can't work. Assume I have an ellipse drawn with `rx=ry=1e-6`. Given big enough image it should be counted as an edge. But you seem to provide no means to detect it.

Comment: So should I add a function `isEdge(r: Double, x: Double, y: Double): (Double) => Boolean` and do my edge detection based on that? What happens when I `Group` them, how to I combine that?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that can work as well. AFAIU "edge detection" in classical meaning is applicable only to raster images. If you want to work with "scaleless images" I don't think there is any other alternative than to go full path of [Vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) in which you effectively have a fixed set of primitives and produce an image combining those primitives (and storing information about all the primitives!). And if each primitive declares its edge and area (as "shapes"!), you can create an algorithm to compute joined edge and area of a group.

Comment: Turning to vector graphics is in a sense similar to writing your code in a monad-style. You don't just write a code for computation - you create an object that encapsulates the computation. And then you can analyze such objects in a different ways. Going back to images, I believe that no method with signature that takes `Double` like your `isEdge` could help for scaleless images as the whole image might be arbitrary small as in my example above. The way is to have classes like `Arc`, `Line`, etc for "edges" (and similarly for areas) and methods to return collection of those objects.

Comment: @SergGr I was thinking of having some sort of `AfterEffect` where I would render the thing into an `Image` and then run my transformations on that. It would (maybe) lower the resolution (temporarily) but it would allow for edge-detection.

Comment: I've learned much about ray-marching recently. I think many aspects of ray-marching could be applied to my program but in a 2d context (distance from shape, etc). This would help greatly with detecting where an edge is or where a shape is in general.